# Problem creating ODBC connection to SQL Server 2008 with Vista

Tags: networking, sql-server, odbc

Well, I'm trying to get a database schema thing working, first I tried just doing it in Linux where I'm more comfortable, but ODBC seems to be a hack there and I couldn't get it to work. So I figured it shouldn't be too hard in Windows..

Ok, so I created a SQL Server Client Alias so that I can simply same `windowsserver` to refer to my SQL server.

Then, I went to the ODBC configuration in Control Panel. I clicked Add in the User DSN section. I chose Native SQL Server (10), and then clicked next. Then I typed a short name and a description and gave the servername as `windowsserver/SQLEXPRESS`

Then, I click next, give it my user name and password and click next. Then, after like 2 minutes it says "Login Timeout Expired"

**What can be wrong here?** I know the server is configured cause I have SQL Server Management Studio opened up with that server in it.

I'm also just trying to connect over regular TCP/IP and my firewall is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that sometime between me testing the connection and setting up the ODBC connection, the server stopped responding. After restarting the server it all worked.

Answer (score 1):

You say you are trying to connect over TCP/IP, however using the server `windowsserver/SQLEXPRESS` will use the default Named Pipe transport.  You have two options:

1. Really use TCP/IP.  Specify the server in the form of `\\windowsserver\SQLEXPRESS` which should tell the driver to use the Network Transport.
2. Enable the Named Pipe transport.  You can do this by going to Start->Programs->MS SQL Server 2008->Configuration Tools->SQL Server Configuration Manager.  Then under the *SQL Native Client Configuration* option make sure the *Named Pipes* is enabled.

Comment: Just tried your first solution, didn't work. Still gives the same login timeout. For solution #2, I don't think Named Pipes are enabled at the server level(for remote access). Named pipes are enabled though on my client already.

Comment: @heavy Actually, I get an error that the connection string is invalid when using that..